# NGINX, PHP5-FPM, Varnish. WP-Admin becomes unresponsive after a while

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, wordpress, varnish

wp-admin becomes unresponsive after like 10 hours of not being logged in. In order to get it working i need to restart php5-fpm.

I'm using NGINX with PHP5-FPM and Varnish.

This is my settings:

php5-fpm.conf

```
pid = /run/php5-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log
log_level = debug
events.mechanism = epoll

include=/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
```

pool.d/www.conf

```
[www]

user = www-data
group = www-data

listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock1
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 20
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
pm.max_requests = 1000

chdir = /
```

NGINX

```
user  www-data;
worker_processes  4;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
worker_rlimit_nofile 40960;

events {
    worker_connections   1024;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
include mime.types;

upstream php {
    server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock1;
}


server {
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        server_name www.example.com;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php;
                listen 8080;
        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include fastcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass php;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

Comment: How do the server resources (CPU usage, memory/swap usage) look before restarting php5-fpm?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen 

This is how it looks.
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2048       2039          8         66          0       1648
-/+ buffers/cache:        390       1657
Swap:          512        198        313

Comment: @TeroKilkanen, However, after adding more ram to the vps the problem still occured. It only happens when I havent been logged in for like 8-10 hours.

Comment: What is exactly "unresponsive"? And how does individual process memory usage look like before and after restart? Please add the information directly to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Set PHP-FPM to ondemand, you're probably reaching the upper limit for worker processes